# Can I use Foursquare API for getting info on brands, using the Users endpoint?

Tags: foursquare

I'm new to foursquare api development and was looking for high level
steps on how to get followers for a particular brand. I'm working for
a business that has its brand on Foursquare and would like to get
information about all the people that checkin to the brand or follow
them so they can send them thank you cards... etc... Is a brand a user infact and can I use the User endpoints to get the list of followers?

Any help would be appreciated...!

Answer (score 0):

Brands have a userId just like normal users and you can access their friend/follower information the same way you'd access it for a regular user.

To encourage new followers, you should consider using a foursquare follow button on the brand's web pages: https://foursquare.com/business/brands/offerings/followbutton

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll be using the user endpoint then to get the info.

Comment: I'll check out the follow button as well.